# Dropdowns based on each other (HTML/JS/Jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am tasked with generating dropdowns that are based on each other, to navigate a page:

I get the following html-fragment with a XmlHttpRequest, I will include all my code.

```
<nav style="display:none;">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <button class="wdbNav level" data-lvl="pa000008-d2e2" title="Navigationsebene einblenden">Module 1 </button>
            <ul id="pa000008-d2e2" style="display: none;">
                <li>
                    <button class="wdbNav level" data-lvl="pa000008-d2e2-d2e6" title="Navigationsebene einblenden">Text</button>
                    <ul id="pa000008-d2e2-d2e6" style="display: none;">
                        <li><a href="intro">intro</a></li>
                        <li><a href="text">text</a></li>
                        <li><a href="translation">translation</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <!-- several entries like the one above -->
                    
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <!-- several elements like the above-->
        </li>
        <li> <!-- this one has a special thing-->
            <button class="wdbNav level" data-lvl="pa000008-d2e364" title="Navigationsebene einblenden">Module 3 </button>
            <ul id="pa000008-d2e364" style="display: none;">
                <li>
                    <button class="wdbNav level" data-lvl="pa000008-d2e364-d2e366" title="Navigationsebene einblenden">Texts 3 and 4 in one list</button>
                    <ul id="pa000008-d2e364-d2e366" style="display: none;">
                        <li>
                            <a href="intro34">intro34</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button class="wdbNav level" data-lvl="pa000008-d2e364-d2e366-d2e371" title="Navigationsebene einblenden">Text 3</button>
                            <ul id="pa000008-d2e364-d2e366-d2e371" style="display: none;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="pa000008-0901">german version</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button class="wdbNav level" data-lvl="pa000008-d2e364-d2e366-d2e377" title="Navigationsebene einblenden">Text 4</button>
                            <ul id="pa000008-d2e364-d2e366-d2e377" style="display: none;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="pa000008-0902">lang1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="pa000008-0903">lang2</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

For every "Module" I want to put the button as a  to dropdown_1
Foe every "Text" I want to put the button to dropdown_2

And whenever I select the option "Module 1" in dropdown_1, the "Text"-options for "Module 1" should be visible. Upon clicking a "Text"-option in dropdown_2, dropdown_3 shoudl be populated with the options for that (in the example a with href=intro34" and "german version", or based on the structure (here comes the last part) it should populate dropdown_3 with the button "Texts 3 and 4 in one list" and a fourth with the sibling-ul content.

I have the following function that does okay when it comes to dropdown_1 and dropdown_2

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/exist/restxq/edoc/collection/pa000008/nav.html');
    request.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
        if (request.status === 200) {
            const htmlResponse = request.responseText;
            const parsedHtml = $(htmlResponse);


            const dropdownContainer = $('#dropdownContainer');

            // Function to populate dropdown from parsed HTML
            function populateDropdown(dropdown, selector, defaultValue) {
                dropdown.empty().append(`<option value="">${defaultValue}</option>`);
                parsedHtml.find(selector).each(function () {
                    const text = $(this).text().trim();
                    dropdown.append(`<option value="${text}">${text}</option>`);
                });
                dropdown.prop('disabled', false);
            }

            // Function to create and append a new dropdown
            function createDropdown(id) {
                const newDropdown = $('<select></select>').attr('id', id);
                dropdownContainer.append(newDropdown);
                return newDropdown;
            }

            // Populate and handle each dropdown
            for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
                const dropdownId = `dropdown_${i}`;
                const currentDropdown = createDropdown(dropdownId);

                // Populate dropdown with buttons at the first level
                populateDropdown(currentDropdown, `> ul > li > button`, `Select Level ${i}`);

                // Handle dropdown change
                currentDropdown.change(function () {
                    const selectedValue = $(this).val();
                    for (let j = i + 1; j <= 3; j++) {
                        const nextDropdown = $(`#dropdown_${j}`);
                        populateDropdown(nextDropdown, `> ul > li > button:contains("${selectedValue}") + ul > li > button`, `Select Level ${j}`);
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            console.log(request);
        }
    });
    request.send();
});
```

some aspects that annoy me:
I cannot change the ids, they are delivered to me like that, automatically generated. might be different each time, I hate this part as well. I can neither change class-names, nor rely on ids, or data-levels as they are not necessarily stable. -.-

I cannot provide a pen, as the API is at the moment hidden ...

it should look somewhat like this:

```
<select id="dropdown_1">
    <option value="">Select Level 1</option>
    <option value="Module 1">Module 1</option>
      <!-- I removed several elements -->
    <option value="Text 3 and 4">Module 3</option>
      <!-- I removed several elements -->
</select>

<select id="dropdown_2">
    <option value="">Select Level 2</option>
    <option value="Text 1 ">Text 1</option>
    <!-- I removed several elements -->
</select>


<select id="dropdown_3">
    <option value="">Select Level 3</option>
    <option value="Text 3 and 4 ">Texts 3 and 4</option>
    <option value="other text"></option>
    <!-- I removed several elements -->
</select>
```

I am searching for a way to do this but I am at a loss after 9hrs today ...
I hope my brain still allows for a halfway coherent  post :-(